# Finding the rare element Omegon

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've been playing the game for some time now, and I have yet to stumble upon any Omegon.  I understand that it is rare, but are there particular environments/planets where it is more common?  I'm currently in need of it to repair one of technologies on my ship.

More so, what does it even look like so I can keep my eyes peeled?

Comment: I have a little Omegon, but I can't recall how I received it. It was either from destroying a level 1 Sentinel (small flying drone) or as a 'deposit' from an animal I fed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Wiki](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Omegon) now contains a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Omgeon Ore]

It also states that Omegon spawns on radioactive planets and you cannot use a scanner to locate it:

> You can find Omegon ore on certain radioactive planets, but it cannot be found with a scanner.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what the wiki says about Omegon:

> There are no known locations yet for mining Omegon, and it cannot be found with a scanner. It glows Purple and floats upon the ground.

However Directly underneath this statement the wiki also says:

> You can find Omegon ore on certain radioactive planets. Create a hole with the Grenade launcher beneath the Omegon ore before extracting it because it often falls in two pieces and rolls down the mountains and even on flat grounds. In this way you can mine it easier.

The wiki states that dismantling Cannon damage Theta or Beam impact Theta will also yield some Omegon.

[Wiki Page](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Omegon)

Comment: For what it's worth I bought mine from the Trade Network.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the existing answer:

If you feed animals on a planet, they will usually "spawn" resources for you afterward, one of which can be omegon.

Comment: They actually spawn resources? I thought they just lead you to them.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Omegon on any planet by salvaging crashed ships and breaking technologies down into resources. This goes for other valuable resources like Gravitino Balls, Dimension Matrix, Gold, Emeril, etc. as well.

When you break techs down into resources, just go back to your original ship and take it back. (so be sure you have parked it where you can find it again, because after you have accepted the new ship, there is no marker pointing back to your original ship)

For this to work however, you need to be sufficiently far into the game in order for you to find ships with applicable technologies installed. But if you need it to repair a tech on a ship, there is a good chance that crashed ships will have that tech too.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen Omegon myself and a quick google searched turned up nothing and neither does [the wiki](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Omegon).

I have gotten it either buying it at space stations or by dismantling certain upgrades on crashed ships. Precious tier ores like Omegon are noted with a green (!) when scanning the planet.

Comment: Anecdotally, it seems more common in Korvax systems. I've found it in three Korvax systems now. The best location I've found was a trading post on a planet of one of these systems. The trading terminal had a little, then the ships which kept docking mostly had some as well. Got two stacks worth from the one place.